# Is there a way to find the nearest cross streets for an address?

Tags: google-maps, street-address

Using the google maps API is there a way to programmatically find the nearest cross streets, given a particular street address?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately the Google Maps API does not provide methods to find the nearest intersection from a particular street address or coordinate. You may want to check the following posts for further reading:

- [Stack Overflow: How can I find the nearest intersection via the Google Maps API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554638/how-can-i-find-the-nearest-intersection-via-the-google-maps-api)
- [Google Groups: Find nearest intersection](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api/browse_thread/thread/504a264ddb5a327c/)
- [Google Groups: Find nearest intersection to a given address](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api/browse_thread/thread/40c9d54664fad323)
- [Google Groups: Another approach to find nearest intersection to the address](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api/browse_thread/thread/e530c2d16f1c0aee/)

Answer (score -3):

maybe this methods could be of interest:

GStreetviewClient.getNearestPanorama(a,b,c)

GStreetviewClient.getNearestPanoramaLatLng(a,b,c)