# iPhone: Turning latitude/longitude into "major cross-streets"

Tags: iphone, google-maps, mapkit, cllocationmanager, mkreversegeocoder

Using the MKReverseGeocoder or GoogleAPI or MapKit...

Is there a simple way to turn a latitude/longitude into "nearest major cross-streets"?

A user might not have any idea where "12345 Pineapple" is located... so I want to show something like "Pineapple and Main"... or (larger, major roads) like "US-140 and Hwy 76".

I don't really care what "major" is defined as... perhaps any road with higher speed limits... or more than 3 lanes... etc.

I don't really care what "close by" is defines as... perhaps within 0-10 miles... or just "closest found".

Comment: do you want to convert numbers to some message like "your are between cross street 1 and cross street 2"?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a built in method to do this with MapKit or the Google API.

See this SO question for some reading about this in relation to the GoogleMaps API:

[Is there a way to find the nearest cross streets for an address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611548/is-there-a-way-to-find-the-nearest-cross-streets-for-an-address)