# Finding common cross street using google maps (or API)

Tags: google-maps, google-api

I'm making an application that uses google maps. The app has a database of schools with their address, coordinates etc. Given addresses of two houses, i want to find the nearest cross street between the two houses and from there I want to plot the path to one of the schools.
Is there any API or framework available.
(I'm looking for similar solution on iOS as well. I'll post a new question for iOS)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The is [no API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612746/1671639), to find the nearest cross street.

Whereas to plot the path between 2 address, you can use Google Maps **[DirectionsService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#DirectionsService)**.

> *A service for computing directions between two or more places.*